# unable to set value to hidden field from jquery

Tags: jquery, html

following is the html code

```
<input id="Jobs[0].TestParameter" name="Jobs[0].TestParameter" type="hidden" />
```

following is the jquery code

```
var ParamArr = [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ];
$("#Jobs[0].TestParameter").val(JSON.stringify(ParamArr));
            alert($("#Jobs[0].TestParameter").val());
```

Comment: why you are using id like Jobs[0].TestParameter?

Comment: i am passing list of objects to .net controller so i need to pass in this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the special characters in your ID tag to fix your problem.

```
$("#Jobs\\[0\\]\\.TestParameter").val(JSON.stringify(ParamArr));
            alert($("#Jobs\\[0\\]\\.TestParameter").val());
```

```js
var ParamArr = [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ];
$("#Jobs\\[0\\]\\.TestParameter").val(JSON.stringify(ParamArr));
            alert($("#Jobs\\[0\\]\\.TestParameter").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Jobs[0].TestParameter" name="Jobs[0].TestParameter" type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

pass simple id `\\` for escape character

```js
var ParamArr = ["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"];
$("#Jobs\\[0\\]\\.TestParameter").val(JSON.stringify(ParamArr));
alert($("#Jobs\\[0\\]\\.TestParameter").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Jobs[0].TestParameter" name="Jobs[0].TestParameter" type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the square brackets(`[]`) and the dot (`.`) so that they are not counted as attribute selectors. Try this

```js
var ParamArr = ["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"];
$("#Jobs\\[0\\]\\.TestParameter").val(JSON.stringify(ParamArr));
alert($("#Jobs\\[0\\]\\.TestParameter").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Jobs[0].TestParameter" name="Jobs[0].TestParameter" type="" />
```